# zend navigation using database

Tags: php, xml, database, zend-framework

how we could create a container for Zend_Navigation instead of xml file use of database table?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

create table with columns {action,controller,ative,privalege ...etc)

then

```
$rows = $db->fetchAll();
$config = Zend_config($rows);
$navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config); or new Zend_Navigation($rows);
```

why this not be used
a)database is slow
b)layered navigation would be mess (one to many relation you ill need to create more tables)